# Reading text from a file using regular expressions

Tags: java

I have a text file containing information that has numbers and characters that are broken into 3 columns and I can't figure out what regular expressions I'm needing. The columns are broken by ; and after the third column is written then it skips to the next line and goes on. I know majority of my code is working properly and I've narrowed down the problem to this section of code.

I've tried looking up java regular expressions and I can't seem to find what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // Searches the file that matches a specific value
    if (!line.isEmpty() || line.matches("Need regular expression here that skips over the two columns and reads the last")) {
        if (isValid(line)) {
            System.out.println(line + "IS Valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println(line + "IS NOT VALID");

        }
    }
}
```

In the console after reading the file it should say

```
"12345";"12";"tacobell@yahoo.com"; IS valid
"123456";"31";"Taco  . bell@yahoo.com"; IS NOT VALID
```

It must contain the whole line when writing out to the console not just the third column.

Comment: Is the second one invalid only because of the space in the email address or also because one of the numbers is invalid?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca it is invalid because it would fail the validation for an email.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^;]*;[^;]*;([^ ]*);$
```

That will give you a match only if the third column contains no spaces (so it will match `"12345";"12";"tacobell@yahoo.com";`, but it will not match `"123456";"31";"Taco . bell@yahoo.com";`).

The parentheses are a capture group, so you can extract that column by grabbing group #1 (not group #0) from the capture results.

The `^` at the beginning means that this pattern has to start at the beginning of a line, and the `$` at the end means that this pattern has to end at the end of a line. If that's not the case for your input, you will have to adjust it. For example, if you had trailing whitespace after the last column, you might do:

```
^[^;]*;[^;]*;([^ ]*);[ ]*$
```

If you had trailing whitespace and the last semicolon was optional, you'd do:

```
^[^;]*;[^;]*;([^ ]*);?[ ]*$
```

One last thing: I'm using `[ ]` to indicate whitespace, but that only includes the basic space character. It doesn't include tabs, newlines, or any other type of whitespace. It's better to use `\s` if you want to include all of those, but in Java string syntax you have to escape the backslash, so it would look like this:

```
Pattern.compile("^[^;]*;[^;]*;([^ ]*);?\\s*$")
```

This is the reason why well-designed programming languages have a specialized regular expression syntax. It gets even crazier if you want to match a literal backslash:

```
Pattern.compile("\\\\")
```

In Javascript, this would just be:

```
/\\/
```